# Ansible & Jinja2: combine a dictionary to each element of a list

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have a variable that is an array `[{'foo':1},{'bar':2}]`.
I want to combine it with the following hash: `{'baz':3}` using a set fact (?) such as my output registered variable is:

```
[{'foo':1, 'baz':3},{'bar':2, 'baz':3}]
```

I've looked into the `combine` filter, but it only works when I already have an hash to work with. In my case I have an array.

Is there a way to achieve that using ansible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I have found a way. `map` can be used with any filters, and arguments have to be passed after a comma

```
- name: test
  set_fact:
    _test: "{{ [{'foo':1}, {'bar':2}] | map('combine', {'baz':3}) | list }}"
```

produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "_test": [
        {
            "baz": 3, 
            "foo": 1
        }, 
        {
            "bar": 2, 
            "baz": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot `map` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja2 doesn't have list comprehension, but I think you can use `set` and `for` loop to achieve it:

```
{% set outputarray = [] -%}
{% for d in inputarray -%}
    {% set r = d|combine({'baz': 3}) -%}
    {{ ouputarray.append(r) and '' }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, can I place that in my ansible playbook, or how do I include this? Never seen code like this

Comment: You can put it in the top of your YAML file, and refer `{{ outputarray }}` in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I learned something. Found a simpler solution too :)